# Connect OAuth Tokens with a user

Tags: c#, authentication, .net-core, oauth-2.0, authorization

I'm trying to figure out the best way to map tokens to a user.  I think I've falling across a common problem Authorization vs Authentication.

I'm creating a market place which, my payments service is backed by stripe so I allow logins using stripe currently.

I register my stripe service like so:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})    
.AddOAuth<OAuthOptions, StripeConnectOAuthHandler<OAuthOptions>>(
    StripeConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => {
    options.SaveTokens = true;
    options.ClientId = Configuration["Stripe:ClientId"];
    options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Stripe:ClientSecret"];
    options.TokenEndpoint = StripeConnectDefaults.TokenEndpoint;
    options.AuthorizationEndpoint = StripeConnectDefaults.AuthorizationEndpoint;
    options.UserInformationEndpoint = StripeConnectDefaults.UserInformationEndpoint;
    options.Scope.Add("read_write");
    options.CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-stripeconnect");
    //...
});
```

Since stripe is what I use to handle the payments I need the token to perform certain behavior like creating a pay event or subscribing to one but I don't want to enforce that my users must have a stripe account to view data on my site.

So I'd like to add additional ways to login, but I need to link these users together

```
app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOptions()
{
    AuthenticationScheme = "Google",
    DisplayName = "Google",
    SignInScheme = COOKIE_AUTH,
    ClientId = "sdlfkjgsdlkfjgsdf-sdfadsfasdf.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    ClientSecret = "myClientSecretBase64==",    
});
```

However if I do this, I need a way to link my google login and my stripe account login.  Prior to now I was using IdentityServer4.  Generally Token Servers are sperate from the API.  So It seems a bit of overkill to host a token server, if only a single application is going to consume it.

Is there a simple way allow authentication, while still giving the ability to connect to external api's such as stripe?

**Note:** If the solution requires IdentityServer 4 I don't mind, I just would rather not having to host 2 seperate applications

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this seems to be caused by a misconception of mine about Identity.  Identity already a single user to have different login methods.  In my authentication controller I fixed this by attaching an external login to an existing user if the user already exist.

```
var user = await this._userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
if(null == user)
{
    user = await this.CreateIdentityUser(info, email);
}

var addLoginResult = await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
```

**Warning:**  You shouldn't be careful linking users, if you irregardlessly link users based on email, you could run into an issue where another user creates a fake account on the provider using the same email.